# Quantum entanglement and superdense encoding etc

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Is the following a somewhat correct analogy for what these phenomenae are?

Imagine a box of thousands of apples where exactly half of each apple is red and the other half is green. Each apple is perfectly symmetrical in shape, color and innards. These are stored in a large container, and let out through a pipe in the bottom, one by one, from there on free falling (rotating randomly) onto a slicing wire. The wire slices each half in two pieces (my analogy to polarization), then one piece goes to Alice, and one to Bob. Each piece arriving to Alice is randomly different from the previous, yet because the apples were originally identical and symmetrical she can totally predict how the pieces Bob recieve look, and furthermore at the same instant as he finds out (or actually before).

If this analogy is somewhat correct, I struggle to see the point of anything quantum related, since the exact same thing could be achieved with apples :)

Now the bashing of me may commence!

Comment: What you describe is a local hidden variable model.  Such models make predicitions (in particular Bell inequalities) which are incompatible with quantum mechanics.

Comment: With my limited maths background (some linear algebra, some discrete maths and probability and stuff), is there anyway that I can understand why the hidden variable ideas are wrong, or would you suggest that I drop it and think of it as just something weird?

Comment: I think even with math background, you can't understand *why* they are wrong. You just have to accept that quantum theory is incompatible with our classical intuition at a very fundamental level.

Comment: Put this way, would I be able to see for myself that it is so by looking at the expressions, or is it hidden too deep within the realms of all this bra-ket mystery?

Comment: If you think that bra-ket is mystery, then you won't see anything by looking at any expressions. Other than that, yes, it is easy to see once you understand the formalism of quantum mechanics why it is inconsistent with local realism. -- But what you can try to understand is Bell's inequality - it has nothing to do with quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analogy is not correct - and it cannot be, because you describe a perfectly valid classical experiment. The problem is that no analogy can be correct, because quantum entanglement is not somthing we can describe by classical physics - hence the need for quantum theory.

The first problem with your experiment is that you have fixed the measurement basis: the "color" of the apple. The second is that you only introduced classical randomness (something randomly picking an apple).

Let's focus on the first problem: If we do the same experiment with an entangled pair of spins (e.g. two particles), then the crucial observation is not that whenever Alice measures "spin up", she knows that Bob will also measure "spin down", but that regardless of which basis Alice chooses ($L_x,L_y,L_z$ or any other), the outcome of her and Bob's measurement are the same.

In a classical system, this cannot be achieved. Somehow, you'd have to be able to also say that an apple is between red and green, i.e. that it could also be of a different kind of colour (let's call it "gred" and "reen") and when Alice gets the apple, she can decide to have a look whether it's red or green, or whether it's gred or reen. Now, whatever Alice chooses to measure, the apple of Bob needs to be the same if Bob measures in the same basis. However, an apple can obviously only have ONE color at a time and whatever it was, it was well-defined from the start (if the apples in the box are green and red, they are green and red, if they are gred and reen, they are either gred or reen, but then, they are not red or green). This is different for the quantum particle.

Let's investigate your experiment in more detail: You have a box of apples with either red $apple_{red}$ or green $apple_{green}$ apples (these are only symbols). You splice the apples and send one half to Alice and one half to Bob, thereby the apples the two have are either $apple_{red,red}$ or $apple_{green,green}$. You said that the probability for having a red or a green apple is exactly one half. This means your system has the state:

$$\rho=\frac{1}{2}apple_{red,red}+\frac{1}{2}apple_{green,green}$$

Now, you measure your system, which means that Alice has a look at the first color of the state (either red or green). If she finds $apple_{red}$, she knows the apple must have been $apple_{red,red}$.

Let's have a look at the quantum system. Here, in order to see entanglement, the state of the apple must be neither red, nor green, it must be all of it. There is somehow only one type of apple and its all $apple_{red+green}$ so that after the splicing, you get a state

$$\rho=apple_{red,red+green,green}.$$

And now, Alice can decide what she wants to measure: If she decides to measure "red" or "green", she simply has a look at whether the apple is red or green - and that happens with probability 1/2. In any case, Bob will measure the same. But maybe, Alice wants to have a look at whether the state is reen or gred. Her outcome will be "reen" with some probability and "gred" with another (meaning that the apple really looks "reen" or "gred", whatever that is. It's not actually "red" or "green" and we just try to decide which of the other colors fits better - no, it's actually "reen" or actually "gred") - and once again, Bob will measure the exact same thing if he also has a look at whether his apple is "reen" or "gred". Here, you also see the "quantum probability": We don't have a box of either red or green apples with some probability each, we have a box with only one type of apple. Yet, when we have a look at the color of the appley, the outcome might be random - something that cannot happen in classical physics.

The correlations between the entangled states are therefore much stronger than in your experiment!

***To summarise:*** To explain a maximally entangled state, you'd have to start out with a box of completely identical apples of a certain type. Then you split the apple and get one half to Alice and the other to Bob. Now Alice decides what pair of colours she wants to measure and measures it. Whatever the outcome, she then knows what the outcome will be on Bob's side.

The differences to your experiment: Alice has several choices for colors. The apple can not just have one out of two colours, but it can have a multitude of colours - however Alice can only ever measure a pair at the same time. Also, instead of a mixture of differently coloured apples, we use only one type of apple that has an undefined colour that gets only defined when Alice has a look.

**Mathematically speaking:** What you describe is not an entangled state, it's a maximally mixed state - and those behave very differently (see [What is the difference between maximally entangled and maximally mixed states?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/170318/what-is-the-difference-between-maximally-entangled-and-maximally-mixed-states))

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful answer. Does it matter that I pictured my apple as being green on one side and red on the other, and that the color varied smoothly? That way the state could be said to be both green and red simultaneously. Also, if Bob and Alice take one random point sample per apple piece, and given four possible outcomes (green, red, greenred or redgreen), then Alice and Bobs measurements would seem correlated but not identical. But I guess I'm missinng the point. Nevertheless, I realized by virtue of me not knowing these things that my analogy was flawed.

Comment: Also if the color is basis Lx, then the number of seeds could be Ly... Just sayin... ;-)

Comment: The trouble with the different colours on one apple is just what you say: If you then define a measurement by picking some points and doing a majority voting or something like this, the outcome on both sides won't be the same all the time and regardless of what you measure. That is exactly where quantum mechanics does something that you cannot do in classical mechanics.

Comment: So you mean that even though Alice measures some state with some probability p=x,  as soon as she has done that then Bob will measure some correlated state with p=1?

Comment: Let's take the perfectly correlated maximally entangled state (there are other ones). Then, yes, regardless what basis Alice took and regardless of the measurement statistics (i.e. regardless of what the probability is that she measures it), she can always perfectly predict Bob's outcome from her own - if they measure both in the same basis.

Comment: If you want want to use different things such as color and seeds, etc. as different measurement bases, this is better. However, there are three problems: One, you can only ever do one measurement - either count the seeds or look at the color. This seems a bit arbitray. Two: The measurement statistics will be different. While maybe if you measure red/green, it turns out that Alice measures red 1/2 of the time, she will maybe always count the same number of seeds. But it gets more complicated:

Comment: Three: In principle you have uncountably many bases for measurements (that is, colour and seeds are not enough) and the different statistics are all interrelated and you can predict them from having the measurement statistics for one basis. I'd advise you to have a look at the basics of entangled states (have a look at the linked article and try to get acquainted with the nomenclature - it is possible to get it also from the mathematical side).

Comment: Regarding the fact that one can only measure on one basis; Not at all arbitrary since to measure the number of seeds you'd have to eat the apple, by when you would have forgotten what color it had! I'll stop now and read the link. You have me lots of inspiration to try to understand some more, and I am still quite happy with my apples analogy! My next one will contain oranges as well ;-) Cheers!

Comment: No, not done yet. You see now I've been reading about the EPR paradox. Suppose every apple has always one seed. How many seeds do half an apple contain? Well onezero of course, it has both one and zero seeds at the same time (which is just another way of saying "dunno yet, haven't checked"). But if Alice know that she has one half and Bob has the other, as soon as one of them checks he/she immediately know the state of the others half as well. Isn't this the same thing? Answer only if you take pleasure in doing so. I know I'm being thick headed here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32785/discussion-between-martin-and-mickey).